# Creating Post Request

Tags: php

I am trying to screen scrape an ASP.NET site that requires a post. Here's all the data. How would I make the post request in PHP ? Do I need to worry about the cookies?

Thanks!

```
    Request URL:http://www.washaware.com/Room.aspx
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:302 Found
    Request Headersview source
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:1978
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=5cmsvb45p3dal24532vzhc55; UniversityIndex=code=pomona47&index=9
    Host:www.washaware.com
    Origin:http://www.washaware.com
    Referer:http://www.washaware.com/Room.aspx
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like         Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
    Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
    ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField:
__EVENTTARGET:ctl00$mainContent$Timer1
__EVENTARGUMENT:

__VIEWSTATE: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
    __EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWFQKzpr+1DAKXkOWVDQKZyt5+ApeQ8ZUNApeQ7ZUNApeQ9ZUNAsSH6MkIApeQ/ZUNAsSH8MkIApeQhZYNAs+05OAPAoWHoIsEArvZ27UIAv+z2HkC8auX4AwC9+r1tg4Cz7Tw4A8ChYesiwQCu9nntQgC8auj4AwC46zfwAlEJL0QH44YGn+jDe9BZAMXiitqHA==
    Response Headersview source
    Cache-Control:private
    Content-Length:129
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Tue, 08 Apr 2014 03:43:21 GMT
    Location:/Room.aspx
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: $_POST['object'] to grab the object value you sent